# How to resolve the error while running react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am getting an error while trying to run the react project using npm start. I have tried to reinstall npm modules and check but it is not working. It gives error as below:

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\91720\Desktop\React js/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\91720\Desktop\React js\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91720\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-30T14_01_45_332Z-debug.log

Comment: Does `C:\Users\91720\Desktop\React js\package.json` exist?

Comment: Hi @darshini try with this command - composer init

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below, if you've deleted your `package.json` file in your project.

1. Create a react application again using `npx create-react-app {app-name}` in a different folder. Then move to that folder (`cd {app-name}`) and check whether `package.json` file does exist.
2. Copy all the files you've created previously into `/src` folder of the newly created app.
3. If you already have the dependencies you used in previously created app, then copy it in dependency section of `package.json` file of newly created app.
4. Run `npm install` in application directory.
5. Check whether npm modules are created again.
6. If it installed perfectly, then run `npm start` to check whether application starts.

Answer (score 0):

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\91720\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-30T14_01_45_332Z-debug.log

This error is because you are not in the current directory
`TYPE cd{app-name}`
Then `npm start`